# Isolated Azure Function bypass authentication middleware for Swagger UI page

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I've created a new .NET 6 **Isolated** Azure Function.
I've added the specific Nuget package for Swagger/OpenAPI (for Isolated):

```
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi v1.3.0
```

I then decorate my HttpTrigger Function with the appropriate `[OpenApiOperation]` attribute and correctly add the `ConfigureOpenApi()` method inside my `Program.cs` like so:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureOpenApi()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Everything works as expected and I can access my swagger UI url:
http://localhost:7001/api/swagger/ui

---

It's now time to protect my Az Function and add support for `JWT token validation`.
To do so, I followed this great article:
https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-jwt-authentication-in-net-isolated-process-azure-functions

Because I'm inside an **Isolated** Azure Function I can now leverage `middleware` and the article does just that. It creates two `middleware`. So I've added them like so:

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults((context, builder) =>
    {
        builder.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>();
        builder.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMiddleware>();
    })
    .ConfigureOpenApi()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**QUESTION:**

Whenever I launch my Azure Function and I try to access my swagger UI url http://localhost:7001/api/swagger/ui

I am now getting a `401 unauthorized` since the `Authentication Middleware` kicks in and since I don't have an `authorization` header value.

I believe it is normal that I don't have an `authorization` header value since I'm only trying to look at a swagger UI url.

How can I ask the `Authentication middleware` to not look for an `authorization` header if I'm coming from an url that has the word "swagger" in it?

Or is there a better/different way to achieve this?

Thanks
Sincerely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware), you can use the `UseWhen` extension method.

you will need to use at least the version **1.8.0-preview1** of the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker` nuget package. (See [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/855#issuecomment-1118915912))

Then in you code you should be able to do something like that:

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults((hostContext, builder) =>
    {
        builder.UseWhen<AuthenticationMiddleware>(functionContext =>
        {
            // Only use the middleware if not related to swagger
            // Condition could be improved tho.
            return !functionContext.FunctionDefinition.Name.Contains("Swagger");
        });
        ...
    })
    ...

host.Run();
```

Comment: You are 100% correct Sir Thomas :-)
Thank you for that UseWhen() gem. It is unfortunate that I need to use the preview Nuget but it'll have to do. Thanks again.

Btw...what is the likelihood of removing the UseWhen() since it's in preview?

Comment: @Vince to be honest, i'm not sure. You could add a comment on the github repo. I would imagine this won't be removed.